# Passing a URL that has spaces inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am a attempting to pass a URL inside a `javascript` `onclick` function but it returns `missing )` error on console log, i experiment on it and found out that the URL contains special characters and sometimes spaces that escape the `onclick` event.

I am getting the url from a `PHP` script

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

and passing it on a onclick event

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="main" onclick="getContent(<?php echo $actual_link;?>);">Content 1</a>
```

My question is how to pass a url text inside a javascript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the php output in order to pass string to function:

```
 onclick="getContent('<?php echo $actual_link;?>');">
                  // ^^                        ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a `''` inside the `getContent` function.

```
onclick="getContent('<?php echo $actual_link;?>');">
```